# What does ($tokenstream:ident as $ty:ty) mean in Rust

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to learn Rust, and want to understand everything in this code block.

```
#[macro_export(local_inner_macros)]
macro_rules! parse_macro_input {
    ($tokenstream:ident as $ty:ty) => {
        match $crate::parse_macro_input::parse::<$ty>($tokenstream) {
            $crate::export::Ok(data) => data,
            $crate::export::Err(err) => {
                return $crate::export::TokenStream::from(err.to_compile_error());
            }
        }
    };
    ($tokenstream:ident) => {
        parse_macro_input!($tokenstream as _)
    };
}
```

My current issue is with `($tokenstream:ident as $ty:ty)`.

1. What is the point of having dollar signs in front of the name for parameters in macro_rules? Does it have any functional purpose?
2. What does the line of code mean? The way I read it is, "use parameter tokenstream of type ident as ty of type ty", and it doesn't make sense to me.

Thank you

Comment: In this case `as` has no "actual" meaning as a Rust keyword; it's just another part of the macro's pattern to match on. You have to write the macro as `x as y` for it to enter the first branch, but it has no deeper meaning than that.

Answer (score 1):

1. The dollar signs in a rust macro signal a "metavariable" and the part after the colon is called "fragment specifier".
   `$foo:ty` is for a type,
   `$bar:ident` is for an identifier,
   more details can be found [here](https://riptutorial.com/rust/example/5646/fragment-specifiers---kind-of-patterns).
2. Since you seem to be interested in the learning rather then just the solution, I'd recommend you to continue reading ["Macros by Example"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html). After going through that, you can probably answer that question 2 for yourself and everybody here. ;)